# How to select records which meet all criteria in linking table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Given these two tables:

**products**

```
product_id         name
1                  shampoo
2                  hairbrush
```

**products_to_categories**

```
id                 product_id    category_id
0                  1             100
1                  1             200
2                  2             100
```

I want to write the SQL which will give me all the products which are in both category 100 and category 200 (i.e. the product with id 1).

(We can assume the existence of the categories table. products_to_categories is a linking table).

```
select p.*, pc.* from products as p
inner join products_to_categories as pc
where pc.category_id = 100 and pc.category_id = 200;
```

Obviously doesn't work because no row has both those values.

I thought about running two selects and then an operation which would find only product_ids in both sets - but UNION is additional rather than subtractive.

This works but is not light-weight;

```
select products.* from products where products.product_id IN (
   select p.product_id from products as p
inner join products_to_categories as pc ON pc.product_id = p.product_id AND pc.category_id = 100   
)
AND
products.product_id IN (
   select p.product_id from products as p
inner join products_to_categories as pc ON pc.product_id = p.product_id AND pc.category_id = 200 

)    ;
```

There must be a nicer way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select p.*
from products p inner join
     products_to_categories pc
     on p.product_id = pc.product_id
where pc.category_id in (100, 200);
group by p.product_id
having count(distinct category_id) = 2;
```

Note:  This uses an ANSI SQL feature that allows you to group by the primary key of a table and reference the rest of the columns.  Not all databases support this feature.  So, in many databases, you would need to list the product fields individually in the `group by`.

Comment: Excellent. Thank-you. Can you explain what the distinct is doing here? My example works without it. Are you allowing for the case that a given product may have two entries in the products_to_categories table with the same category_id?

Comment: But there is a possible problem. This just tells me that product_id 1 is in two categories? In my actual case there are more than 2 categories and a product could be in two categories but not the right two. (No way that was obvious from my question I appreciate)

Comment: @JustinWyllie . . . The `WHERE` clause only looks at two categories, so it works fine for products in multiple categories.  The `distinct` is probably not necessary.  It is only needed if the table can have duplicates.